# Mac Mini requires password to create directory on external drive, but not internal drive. Huh?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, passwords, file-permissions

MacMini logs-itself-in on boot. Plug in a utility external drive, drag a folder from internal drive to blank external, password required. Make a directory on internal drive, no problem. Copy a file to new folder, no problem. Why?

If we pre-load matching folder names on the external utility drive, on a different computer, we can then copy the contents of a folder of that same name from the internal or external drives on the Mini to the utility drive. So Bob/Apple can't be dragged to a blank external drive, but if we create /Bob we can drag the contents of the source Bob folder to the /Bob on the utility drive. The directories are multi-gigabyte monsters, so we pre-load /Bob with subdirectories Apple, baker, charlie, dog, egg, foxtrot, etc. and copy 2 hours worth at a time...

If someone challenged us to setup a Mac so that it auto-logged-in, but required a password to create directories on an external drive, AND allowed copying of sub-directories, without a password, if the top-level directory names matched, I wouldn't know how to do it.

From troubleshooting Windows and MacOS problems in the past, I suspect there may be a group permission issue of some kind.

This is Family IT: Recently departed owner left no hint to their AppleID, iPhone or iPad access codes or computer password. Luckily, they set the computer to log in automatically on power-up.

Surviving Spouse has marriage certificate, death certificate, decades of tax records, typical living trust. Last time we faced this, a marriage certificate, death certificate and possibly the will/trust document were sufficient for Apple to reset the AppleId so surviving spouse could use phone, computer, etc. But now, Apple requires the trust to be re-issued with the deceased owner's name removed. Otherwise, there's nothing they can do. That's a lawyer visit too far, so we've been improvising.

The late owner's iPad and iPhone are bricks, but we can copy files from the Mini- pictures, stories and genealogy, of course. As long as we pre-load the top level directory structure to the utility disk.

The late owner was a lightroom enthusiast and had an external disk farm with all photos on one drive, a backup of that drive, a backup of lightroom, etc., etc., etc. And more that might be of interest to survivors, if they could have a copy. So we've succeeded in doing that, but its really bizarre behavior. Can anyone explain what causes it?  Just so we know not to do "that", whatever it is.

Comment: Are you familiar with traditional Unix filesystem permissions, and command line tools like `ls -l` and `chmod`? I ask because getting to the bottom of the behavior you're seeing may require inspecting these files' and folders' owners, groups, permissions, and ACLs.

Comment: You can set any non-boot drive to 'ignore ownership' with a single clock. However, you need an admin password to do this. Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac for how to create a new admin account.

Comment: Spiff - Yes, and no, I haven't looked there, yet, because the late owner of the system was very much not a Unix-in-the-shell Mac user. Never grepped or even tried "ls -ltFA", to my knowledge. 
Tetsujin - That's the "Awful Warning" part of this story. Without a admin password or an AppleID. we're left to be grateful for the auto-login. Write it down somewhere that your survivors can find. Encode if you must, encrypt only in an emergency. What's wanted is plain text written by hand that anyone can use, but without any hint what it is.